# Select values from another table with most recent entry

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 MySQL Tables:

Table with all Events

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | Eventtitle          |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | Event 1             |
|  2 | Event 2             |
|  3 | Event 3             |
|  4 | Event 4             |
+----+---------------------+
```

Table with user attend statuses - Users can change their status multiple times. Every time they change it, a new entry is inserted into the table

```
+----+------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| id | event_id   | user_id  | status  | attend_time         |
+----+------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | 1          | 2        | 1       |2013-07-03 15:34:02  |
|  2 | 1          | 2        | 2       |2013-08-03 19:01:02  |  <--
|  3 | 3          | 1        | 1       |2013-07-03 15:34:02  |
|  4 | 4          | 4        | 3       |2013-07-03 15:34:02  |
|  5 | 4          | 6        | 2       |2013-07-03 15:34:02  |
|  6 | 4          | 6        | 1       |2013-07-03 18:55:02  |  <--
+----+-----------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

Now I want all events listed and additionally the most recent attend `state` and `attend_time` of the currently logged in user (for example user_id 2 oder 54) - IF he is not in the attend table i still need an entry of the event. (in that case a NULL for the `state` and `attend_time` would be good)

Here I rebuild the Data Structure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1b3f

IF there is no way on how to get the result with MySQL - I will try to get it with PHP

Comment: can you please explain how the result list you are wanting should look like? it should contain the most recent state of the current user(2), i know - but what else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Comment: @northkildonan: It should contain:

event_id | event_title   | status | attend_time
   1     | Event 1       |    2   | 2013-08-03 19:01:02

First 2 are from events table and last 2 are from status table. But as you can see, it should NOT be the status with ID 1 but the status with ID 2

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT s.id, eventtitle, status, attend_time
FROM events e
JOIN status s ON e.id = s.event_id
WHERE user_id = 2 AND attend_time = (SELECT MAX(attend_time) FROM status
                                       WHERE user_id = 2)
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e5b33/6)**

Or:

```
SELECT s.id, eventtitle, s.status, s.attend_time
FROM events e
JOIN status s ON e.id = s.event_id
LEFT JOIN status s2 ON s.attend_time < s2.attend_time
WHERE s.user_id = 2 AND  s2.attend_time IS NULL
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e5b33/8)**

Comment: I have tried to use your solutions here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1b3f/2

but they seem not to work since it's not listing results if the filtered user has no entry in the second table

Answer (score 0):

(not tested)

```
SELECT a.id, eventtitle, status, attend_time FROM events b JOIN status a ON b.id = a.event_id WHERE user_id = 2 order by attend_time desc
```